# Passing tab delimiter through via parameter not splitting string

Tags: javascript, jquery

My issue essentially is, I have a select box that has 2 options `"Tab or CSV"`, those options meaning what to split a string on, my issue is when every I pass through `"\t"` as a parameter, it doesn't split on tabs. if I explictly type `"\t"` it splits the string but not if its being passed via a parameter.

I am trying to create a sql results to `jira table chrome extention`

The issues reside in the `GetDelimiterType` function and `GenerateLine< first line`.

I have no idea what is going on, if i check the value of `delimerType` it reads `"\t"` but doesn't split

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    var textToChange = $("#input").val().split("\n");
    var topLineRow = $("#topRow").prop("checked");
    var delimiterType = $("#delimiterSelect option:selected").val();
    var jiraTable = "";
    debugger;
    if(topLineRow){
        jiraTable += GenerateLine("||", textToChange[0], GetDelimiterType(delimiterType))
    }
    topLineRow = false;
    var generatedString = "";
    $.each(textToChange, function(index, value){
        if(!topLineRow){
         jiraTable +=  GenerateLine("|", textToChange[index],GetDelimiterType(delimiterType));
        }
    })

    alert(jiraTable);
})

function GetDelimiterType(delimiterType){
    debugger;
    if(delimiterType == 0){
        return ",";
    }else if(delimiterType == 1){
        return "\\t";
    }
}
function GenerateLine(seperator, row, delimiter){
    var rowArray = row.split(delimiter);
    var rowText = "";
    $.each(rowArray, function(index, value){
        var isLastElement = index == rowArray.length -1;
        value = value.replace(/\s/g,'');
        if(index == 0){
            rowText += seperator;
        }
        if(isLastElement){
            rowText += value + seperator + "\n";

        }else{
            rowText += value + seperator;
        }
    });
    return rowText;
}
```

Comment: Did you try: `return "\t";`  (ie don't escape the escape, otherwise you're not splitting on tab but instead your splitting on `"\" + "t"`)

Answer (score 0):

## `.split(/.../)`

`.split()` method can pass a regex literal as a delimiter.

> ```
>   /\b[^\S]+?\b|,\s/
> ```

- `\b`oundary meta-sequence denotes a non-spaced character next to a word character
- `[^\S]+?` class ignores one or more non-whitespace characters
- `\b` as above
- `|,\s` OR a  literal comma followed by a space

### Demo

```js
var row = `Mike, Alpha, Tango, Tango  Zulu  Echo  Romeo 0 0 November  Echo`;

var rowArray = row.split(/\b[^\S]+?\b|,\s/);

console.log(JSON.stringify(rowArray));
```